# Long polling server principle (client identification)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsonp

I want to create a simple long polling server in node.js where communication will be based on jsonp requests. I understand that client makes request and server holds response until some data are ready or certain timeout is reached, and then new request from client is made to keep the things going. Once the first request is made, session ID is generated and stored to keep the list of actively connected clients. Now how do I identify that any other request, after the first response from server to client, belongs to which client in my list of active connections?

I can imagine to do it like this: first response from server send assigned session ID to client, and then he is identified based on this ID when making next requests. But I think this approach can be easily exploited and vulnerable to identity theft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [cookie](https://github.com/jed/cookie-node).

Next step for me would be to use SSL, if i was worried about ID theft.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing all that code yourself, I'd suggest that you go with a working and *tested* solution:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO

Socket.IO handles all the connection stuff for you, and it automatically selects the best possible connection Method, like WebSockets and falls back gracefully if they are not available.

Comment: I know about Socket.IO, but this is just hobby stuff created for my pleasure if you know what I mean :).

Comment: Well then let me say that JSONP is the worst possible choice, it's the most insecure way of doing the messaging, since it directly executes the JavaScript (including any function in there).

Comment: The problem is in the same origin policy and JSONP is (to my knowledge) the only way which works across all browsers. Even google is using it for various stuff (for example http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html ).